# Where is my mistake on solving $\int_{0}^{x}\sin(a(x-s))\sin(bs)ds = \frac{a\sin(bx) - b\sin(ax)}{a^{2} - b^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $0 < x < l < \infty$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\sin(a(x-s))\sin(bs)ds = \frac{a\sin(bx) - b\sin(ax)}{a^{2} - b^{2}}.
$$
I know
$$
\sin(bs)\sin(a(x-s)) = \sin(ax)\cos(as)\sin(bs) - \cos(ax)\sin(as)\sin(bs)],
$$
and
$$
\sin(ax)\int_{0}^{x}\cos(as)\sin(bs)ds = \sin(ax)\bigg[\frac{a\sin(ax)\sin(bx) + b\cos(ax)\cos(bx)}{a^{2} -b^{2}}\bigg]
$$
and
$$
\cos(ax)\int_{0}^{x}\sin(as)\sin(bs)ds = \cos(ax)\bigg[\frac{b\sin(ax)\cos(bx) - a\cos(ax)\sin(bx)}{a^{2} - b^{2}}\bigg]
$$
So, the sum of the two equations above is equal to
$$
\frac{a\sin(bx)[\sin^{2}(ax)+\cos^{2}(ax)]}{a^{2} - b^{2}} - \frac{b\sin(ax)[\cos(ax)\cos(bx)-\cos(ax)\cos(bx)]}{a^{2} - b^{2}} 
$$
But the right side of the above equation is zero, I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is $L$? It's not used.

Comment: @GaryLiang a finite number. Changed the lyrics, review.

Comment: Please avoid subject lines that consist of Mathjax code alone; it messes up certain navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and
> $$
> \sin(ax)\int_{0}^{x}\cos(as)\sin(bs)ds = \sin(ax)\bigg[\dfrac{a\sin(ax)\sin(bx) + b\cos(ax)\cos(bx)}{a^{2} -b^{2}}\bigg]
> $$

This is incorrect, you forget to subtract the term when you plug in $s=0$ to your antiderivative, it should be

$$\sin(ax)\int_{0}^{x}\cos(as)\sin(bs)ds = \sin(ax)\bigg[\dfrac{\color{red}{-b}+a\sin(ax)\sin(bx) + b\cos(ax)\cos(bx)}{a^{2} -b^{2}}\bigg]$$

After you put this term back, you will get the desired result.

$$\int_{0}^{x}\sin(a(x-s))\sin(bs)ds = \dfrac{a\sin(bx) - b\sin(ax)}{a^{2} - b^{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the formula
$$\sin \alpha \sin \beta = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(\alpha-\beta) - \cos(\alpha+\beta))$$
from the start.
So we have your integral being equal to:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x \cos((a+b)s-ax) -\cos((b-a)s+ax) ds &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{\sin((a+b)s-ax)}{a+b}-\frac{\sin((b-a)s+ax)}{b-a}\right]_0^x \\
&= \dfrac{a\sin(bx) - b\sin(ax)}{a^{2} - b^{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: But $\alpha = a(x-s)$ and $\beta = bs$, then $\alpha - \beta = -(a+b)s + ax$ and $\alpha + \beta = (b-a)s + ax$

Comment: Got it, you're using that $\cos$ is even and putting - in evidence. So in the first $\cos$, you are using $-(\alpha - \beta)$.

Comment: But why is my account not working?

Comment: The reason why your approach doesn't work is because $$\int_{0}^{x}\cos(as)\sin(bs)ds = \dfrac{a\sin(ax)\sin(bx) + b\cos(ax)\cos(bx)-b}{a^{2} -b^{2}}$$

Comment: @GaryLiang In your solution when you are going to take the minimum between (a+b) and (b-a) the term that will multiply $\sin(bx)$ would not be the
$$
\dfrac{(b-a)\sin(bx) + (a+b)\sin(bx)}{-(a^{2}-b^{2})}
$$